# Maven - Handling Snapshot Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have the following maven dependency in my web application POM, which in turn should pull other dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.libraries</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-libs</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**NOTE** I had release 1.5 for `my-libs` artifact previously pulled during an older build. But I have later upgraded the version to `1.6-SNAPSHOT`. `mathlibrary` artifact wasn't present in `1.5` release.

I am expecting some jars to be present as part of `my-libs` artifact verson `1.6-SNAPSHOT` which wasn't present in `1.5` - the pOM is below:

```
<!-- all the usual POM descriptionsm for my-libs -->

<groupId>com.my.libraries</groupId>
<artifactId>my-libs</artifactId>
<version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- continues... all normal stuff, nothing to see here :'/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my</groupId>
            <artifactId>mathlibrary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>  
<!-- continues -->
```

I expected that `mathlibrary` jar would be pulled if I do `mvn package` for my project. But when I looked at the `lib` folder for my webapplication the jar wasn't there. I then checked my `.m2` directory contents and it seems that only version `1.5` is present, so 1.6-snapshot wasn't automatically installed. From here, I am thinking that if a release version is pulled before, it doesn't pull the next SNAPSHOT?

After I manually installed `my-libs` artifact using `mvn clean install` - on the next build for my web application it pulled the jars correctly. Does this mean that my `package` phase is defined not to automatically pull the SNAPSHOT dependencies? or is this something expected (i.e. I have to manually run `install` phase it if it's not a release version) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mvn package` pulls all SNAPSHOT dependencies from your local repository (and also updates your local repository from a remote repository every 24 hours, if the artifact comes a remote one).

I do not really understand what you mean by "*manually* installed `my-libs`" because there is no automatic way to install artifacts (except for CI servers, that install/deploy on checkin). If you want to use an artifact (like my-libs), you need to build it and put it in the local repository -- and you do this by using `mvn install`.

Comment: I meant that adding the dependency for `my-libs` in my we application project would have also automatically downloaded `mathlibrary` since it was added in `my-libs` as dependency. But it didn't happen when I ran `mvn package` phase. If I want this as a MUST when I am doing a clean package for my web application, what shall I do?

Comment: If you have a dependency on my-libs and my-libs depends on mathlibrary, also mathlibrary will be drawn. Look at `dependency:tree` to verify this. Make sure that all dependencies are in `<dependencies>` and _not_ in `<depenencyManagement>` and that all versions are correct.

Comment: I have updated the question with my previous release info for `my-libs`. Perhaps my confusion will make more sense to you.

Comment: I forgot that there was "Update" button that needs clicking

Comment: If you reference 1.6-SNAPSHOT and do `mvn package`, the version 1.6-SNAPSHOT is pulled. If it is not available, the maven build fails. Maven does not "replace" versions by older versions or release versions. There are different possible sources of error: Maybe you did not build the revision of your project you wanted to build (different branch, wrong build server etc.), maybe you got 1.6-SNAPSHOT but an _older_ version of it (try `mvn package -u`) or some other confusion happened. But I can assure you: If you write 1.6-SNAPSHOT, you get 1.6-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: The update time of 24 hours can simply reduced by using `mvn -U ..` on Maven command line and the check will made each time you build...

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question depends on which `packaging` you are using in your `pom.xml` and on which plugins have executions tailored to the `packge` phase. When dependencies are processed, Maven usually resolves them, which means that corresponding jar files will be in your local repository.
Getting jar files in your `target` folder (as is, or unpacked) is a result of some plugin's work (such plugin would execute a mojo at `prepare-package` or `package` phase (usually). So, make sure you use proper `packaging` (such as `war`) or e.g. "assembly" plugin (which can repack dependencies for you).
To make your dependency artefacts available for resolution and further use, you should either `deploy` them to a remote repository, or `install` them to local repository.

Comment: updated my question, probably now my confusion will make more sense to you?

Comment: The `pom` packaging does not anything with dependencies (see here about mapping between packaging, lifecycle phases and plugins: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). So, from your questions I can conclude, that answer is "no, package phase does not pull dependencies automatically". However in your pom file in the `build` section you may have something like a "dependency" plugin with executions tailored to `package` phase which could do this.

Comment: @scrutari This is wrong. You can reference pom-type dependencies and the content of the pom becomes transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @JFMeier answer on this, I did the following:

1) Removed all release/snapshots from my `.m2` directory.

2) Changed my web app POM to use `1.5` release for `my-libs`

3) Kicked off the build.

4) Once the build finishes, I confirm that `mylibraries` jar hasn't been deployed in my final web application directory in tomcat's WEB-INF\lib

5) Repeated steps 2-4 - BUT changed the version to `1.6-SNAPSHOT` for `my-libs`.

6) Now I can see the expected result.

Answer (score -2):

Maven is only getting into repository (either global or local) when you make a mvn install. With Maven Install, Maven checks if all the POM libraries are present in your project and downloads from repositories into your project if some are missing. If you do a Maven package, it only packages the libraries present in your project.

Comment: So if I do clean compile package It should download from repo?

Comment: Maven also downloads dependencies if you use `mvn package`, but it does not put the result of the build into the local repository.